# Burn [xlworkbook]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just noticed there's an [xlworkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlworkbook) tag, with just over 30 questions.

IMO that tag is wildly redundant, since at a glance every single question tagged with it is *also* tagged with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) (except 4), which is definitely sufficient, regardless of the language tag (all "xlworkbook" questions seem to have a proper language tag, be it VBA, Python, or Java).

Given how the tag is used, I can't think of a single reason for it to exist. Note, I hang around the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tags every day. It really, really looks like a "placeholder" tag that's there just to fill a spot in a question's tag list, without bringing anything meaningful to the table.

Why would we need [xlworkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlworkbook)? And if we don't need it, can we watch it burn? :)

I could go and single-handedly edit/retag all these questions, but I thought I'd ask here first.

---

UPDATE: I've gone ahead and removed the [xlworkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlworkbook) tag everywhere, replacing it with the appropriate interop framework where appropriate, and removing [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) in the process, too.

Comment: Good on ya for posting here, but I'd probably go ping a few other excel answerers to chime in too; critically, it's not at all unusual for questions with a specialized tag to always also have a more general tag - most [tag:boost] questions are also tagged [tag:c++], most [tag:pandas] questions are tagged [tag:python], etc. In this case it may not matter, but for larger tags it can help folks follow the subset that they're interested in / search the subset they need.

Comment: [At least one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53745250/4088852) appears to be using the tag to refer to the [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) library, which apparently used to be named XLWorkbook when it was on CodePlex. The rest of it appears to be mis-use.

Comment: @Comintern I've re-tagged that one with the [tag:closedxml] tag, which looks very much like it might have been the original intent behind the [tag:xlworkbook] tag. I'll go ahead and edit the 30-some questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that [xlworkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlworkbook) is redundant, as a workbook is the standard container within which Excel files live. I do more Excel VBA work than most programmers, I'm guessing, but am by no means an expert... is there a way to use Excel where you are not also working with a workbook? I'm not aware of one.

It's important to note that, because this tag is used by fewer than 50 questions, it qualifies for the [abbreviated burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2756409):

> If you have **authoritative** <sup>a</sup> knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have **conferred** with at least one other [trusted community member](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), *and* are dealing with a tag that has a **small number** of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little *ad hoc* help.
>
> <sub>a)  someone who earned at least a bronze badge in a related, involved and/or impacted tag. (for example, if you have a c# bronze tag we expect you to know if c#-9.0 should be burned, or if you are a follower of a specific tag that constantly get mistagged with a bad tag).</sub>

Even though I agree with you on this burnination, I am unfortunately ~4k short of the "trusted user" requirement. Find one of those users who agrees and you would be greenlit to go ahead and remove these tags yourself, after which point the tag will be deleted from the system overnight.

Comment: Thanks! Edits completed.